# Deploy C# application with an option for trial and full version

Tags: c#, deployment, installation-package

I have developed a c# desktop application, and want to deploy it with some detailed options like

1. User will select to install either a trial version or the full version, during installation  itself.
2. User will fill his registration information during installation only, which will be saved in database.
3. And used will get a check box to launch the application after setup completes.

I have developed this application in Visual Studio 2008 and currently aware of the default deployment process only. Please help with some tutorial link or detailed procedure which will guide step by step for customizing the installation package.